# Is there a VHDL equivalent to Verilog's @(*), i.e., automatic process sensitivity list

Tags: vhdl

It is easy to update a combinatorial process and forget to update the sensitivity list. In Verilog the @(*) was introduced to say the sensitivity list is what is used in this process. Is there an equivalent in VHDL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.vhdl/browse_thread/thread/9b40e0d6b606f643) in comp.lang.vhdl. Sounds like VHDL-2008 adds wildcard sensitivity with `process(all)`, but tool support varies.

Answer (score 3):

If you can not use VHDL-2008 yet, [Sigasi HDT](http://www.sigasi.com/documentation/user/linting.html#quickfixes) can automatically insert the correct sensitivity list for you.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs [VHDL-mode](http://www.iis.ee.ethz.ch/~zimmi/emacs/vhdl-mode.html) can update them too.  That's what I will go with.